# Are spores an issue in sauteed pepper storage when you add garlic?

Tags: food-safety, storage-lifetime, oil, garlic, chili-peppers

Typical food-storage for leftover sauteed or roasted peppers in oil, non-canned, seem to vary from one to two weeks when referencing online sources. However, if I make Hungarian peppers in oil with garlic, sauteeing until lightly browned, then left in the oven with a lid to soften, will the storage lifetime reflect standard peppers in oil, or will the issue of botulism spores shorten the timing due to inclusion of fresh garlic? In particular, once the leftover food is refrigerated, on what factors should I calculate storage lifetime?

- Does cooking until the peppers brown lightly, then braising help eliminate the issue of botulism carried by the garlic?
- Does the pH of the peppers carry enough weight to consider the result acidulated? (If so, how would I compare the acidity of a given pepper as it contributes to the pH of the final product?)
- What is a reasonable storage lifetime?
- Are there any finishing steps I could take to better preserve the peppers in oil when not made in the context of a canning/pressure-cooking operation?

Comment: To clarify, you're storing these refrigerated below 40°F?

Comment: @derobert yes, I'm just looking for some idea of time to trash of refrigerated leftovers

Comment: @mfg - to give you a guide, please clarify when the garlic goes in and in what form (sliced diced skinned?).

Comment: @klypos each clove is crushed, peeled, then put through a garlic press into hot oil sauteed until soft, then peppers added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It seems that temperatures in excess of 250°F for an extended period of time will destroy a significant percentage of the botulism spores but I cannot find a definitive, science based answer on botulism spore death.
2. [Acidifying garlic can take three days to one week](http://anrcatalog.ucdavis.edu/pdf/7231.pdf) when stored in vinegar, so I would assume the pH will not carry enough weight.
3. As long as it's in the refrigerator, you've got a few days, at least.
4. How much are you making at one time? You can [freeze garlic in oil](http://anrcatalog.ucdavis.edu/pdf/7231.pdf) and keep it for months that way. Googling suggests that freezing peppers in oil is a common technique, too, so you should be able to store the entire thing in the freezer for months. You could make a large batch and freeze them in ready-to-use portions and be confident that your food is safe.